# How can I get the content of a url-request into a String in java flash-actionscript

Tags: flash, actionscript, html-content-extraction, urlrequest

How can I get the content of a requested url, that returns an html-page, passed into a string, with java in flash actionscript.
?!
I have this for now

```
var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://somedomain.com/index.php");
var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
loader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, handleVariables);
loader.load(req);
```

what do I have to write in the function handleVariables?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `URLLoader.data` property will contain the decoded variables in the form of an `Object`. One way to retrieve them would be the following:

```
function handleVariables(event:Event):void {
    var loader:URLLoader = event.target as URLLoader;
    for (var key:String in loader.data)
        trace(key, loader.data[key]);
}
```